# What is SetCompatibilityVersion inside of the startup class of asp.net Web API core project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Using Visual Studio 2017, I just created a simple API project as shown below.
And in the Startup.cs file I have this code.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

}
```

Can someone please throw some light as to what is means? Do we need to keep this code?

I think MS should put some comments to indicate what such code does.

[image: SetCompatibilityVersion]

Comment: I've you see this post https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/compatibility-version?view=aspnetcore-2.2 "By opting in, you get the latest behavior, and the long-term behavior of ASP.NET Core" otherwise The SetCompatibilityVersion method allows an app to opt-in or opt-out of potentially breaking behavior changes introduced in ASP.NET Core MVC 2.1 or later.

Comment: ....therefore, the above code sets the compatibility mode to ASP.NET Core 2.2.

Comment: What do you guys mean by compatibility mode and optin optout

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When you call the `AddMvc` method, several components are registered with certain options. You call one method and the whole mvc framework is wired up.

However, if the mvc team in the future decides to change a default value, or decides that a component is no longer to be registered by default, or changes an expected side effect of this method, the user code relying on that would break. To avoid such breakage, you can call the set compatibility method which the mvc team will use to preserve the behavior provided to you.

Suppose they introduce a new feature, which exists only when you are targeting the 2.3 platform: if your code declares that it targets the 2.2 api, the mvc team will know that you are not using that feature because it was not existing at that time. This way the can make safe assumptions about what should be provided and how.

For further details, please look at [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/compatibility-version?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Comment: It's a pity there is no clear description what will break (which is the most important for developers) when changing Version_2_1 <-> Version_2_2

Answer (score 12):

FYI, `SetCompatibilityVersion` is a no-op for .Net Core 3 or later and deprecated in .Net 6.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/compatibility-version?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: I see it says "no-op for .NET Core 3" in the doc, but it does not say "or later". Can anyone clarify on this?

Comment: So far, so good. It is still no-op in .Net 7. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/compatibility-version?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 10):

Yennefer's answer is great, i'll just add some things.

- For ASP.NET Core 2.X it might very well be needed to use `SetCompatibilityVersion`, for the reasons Yennefer described.
- For ASP.NET Core 3.0 it's a no-op, meaning it does absolutely nothing. [Read more here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/compatibility-version?view=aspnetcore-3.1).
- For ASP.NET Core 3.X (but not 3.0) and forward, it might have a value. [Read more here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/compatibility-version?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: so for the Core 5 and above should it be used at all? Or we can remove this?

Comment: It seems to me here that microsoft hasn't updated [their official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/compatibility-version?view=aspnetcore-5.0) @Eru so I don't know. But if you find something please provide a link here and I can update the answer

Comment: Sure, but for now I have just removed that part of setup and all looks as working with no problem. But I guess that any possible break/error would happen during certain runtime scenarios; usage of old nugets etc.